# Windows 10 Lock Screen: No Keyboard

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, on-screen-keyboard

I upgraded my Surface Pro 3 from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 via ISO on the launch date and noticed a strange behaviour when using it without the physical keyboard attached. When I boot or lock the device and it enters the lock screen, tapping the PIN (or password) field *should* trigger the special on-screen keyboard for me to enter the PIN/password, but it doesn't. I have to go through the accessibility menu on the bottom-right to trigger the generic on-screen keyboard in order to type in my PIN/password. This generic keyboard is obviously not fit-for-purpose so I'm hoping someone has a clue here on what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**

This tip seems to have helped somewhat.

Go to Settings > Devices > Typing

Enable the option *Automatically show the touch keyboard in windowed apps when there's no keyboard attached to your device.*

I will test this further and mark this as an answer if this proves to solve the problem.

http://www.windowscentral.com/auto-display-touch-keyboard-windows-10-desktop-mode

---

**Update 1**

This still happens intermittently, though during the first login after the update was installed, the correct on-screen keyboard managed to pop up.

---

This got resolved in the August 11th cumulative update. Not sure why either.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue on Surface 4.    we use a GPO (do not display lock screen)  if this was enabled,  on reboot the keyboard would not work.  if we set to "not configured"  the keyboard would appear after rebooting.   also found that a complete shutdown and power up,  would allow for the keyboard to appear.

Answer (score -1):

On MY computer (ThinkPad yoga 3), when the computer is showing the lock screen in tablet mode, the keyboard only shows up in portrait mode after a long delay. It never shows up in landscape mode. That means you have to TURN the computer so the screen rotates to portrait mode to get the keyboard to appear and even then it takes 10 to 20 seconds. That is the only way to enter the password to unlock the computer in tablet mode.

Comment: Why don't you update your answer with such a simple explanation. It was helpful. Thanks

Comment: This is more of your opinion than your answer. What we want are hard facts rather than your experience.