# How to lock Windows 10 screen without a keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, lock-screen, lock

I know I can lock windows (in particular I'm using windows 10) via the keyboard with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. However, if I don't have a keyboard attached is there a way to lock the session with just the mouse?

I know I can sign out by right-clicking the start menu and choosing Shut down or Sign out but I just want to lock it.

Comment: may be this helps: http://superuser.com/questions/954803/windows-10-lock-screen-no-keyboard

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Click Start, then click your username/picture at the top and select **Lock** from the menu. This also works on Windows 8.1.

[image]

You may have to enable this menu item from your power settings:

1. Click Start, then **Settings**
2. In the window that opens, click **System**, then select **Power & sleep** from the menu to the left
3. Click **Additional power settings**
4. Click **Choose what the power button does** from the menu to the left
5. Click **Change settings that are currently unavailable**
6. Check the checkbox that says **Lock - Show in account picture menu** at the bottom
7. Click **Save changes**.

[image]

Comment: I think this is probably the way to go ;)

Comment: and how do you ***type*** something if you have no keyboard? Did you read the question?

Comment: My bad - answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a shortcut to the following command:

`rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation`

This will return you to the same screen as <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

EDIT: As noted by @BenN - Use the command `tsdiscon` instead as rundll32 has been depreciated.

Comment: This is pretty good although I'm still interested in an answer that wouldn't require setting something up in advance

Comment: **Danger!** `rundll32.exe` is [deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643) and very full of pitfalls. Use `tsdiscon` to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

Just found another way to do this (in Windows 10 at least).  Not ideal but does physically work:

Click `Start Menu -> Settings -> Ease of Access -> Keyboard` and turn on the On-Screen keyboard and then click Window Key followed by the L key.